# AP64501 problem

Tags: step-down

I have a big problem with the AP64501. I used the reference layout from the datasheet for my own PCB (5V output (without C4 and C6)).
As soon as I put 24V on the input, the AP64501 burns out immediately.
After that Vin and GND are shorted.
On the 5V side there is only one LED with 430 Ohm resistor as load.
At an input voltage lower than 20V the circuit works (with strange noises from the coil).
Actually the AP64501 should be able to handle input voltages up to 40V.
This way I have, so far, burned out 15 chips. from 2 different batches.
Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

( The first picture is the reference design of DIODES,
The second picture is my PCB and the third picture is the pinout of the AP64501).

[image: Layout from Datasheet]

[image: My PCB]

[image: Pinout AP64501]

Comment: What type of capacitor did you use for the 22µF output caps, as well as for the 2.7nF compensation cap? What happens when you add C6 (the "optional" 33pF compensation cap)?

Comment: These problems generally come from insufficient input filtering (I say insufficient but you can read it as "bad" or "no"). Make sure the input capacitor (10u) is soldered properly. You can also try using multiple capacitors (e.g. 2x 4u7 or 3x 3u3, larger size) to meet the ripple current requirements. Or you can place a pi filter to the input. Also you can try increasing the input voltage gradually to see if the chip explodes as before. Also as Hearth mentioned, if there's a long input cable then you can expect >40V at input even though the supply voltage is 24V.

Answer (score 2):

How long of a cable is your 24 V power cord?

With a sufficiently long power cord (and "sufficiently long" doesn't even have to be all that long) and a sufficiently low-ESR input capacitor (like an MLCC, which it appears you've used here), the power cord's parasitic inductance can resonate with the input capacitor to produce a spike of as much as double the input voltage. The fact that the problem goes away when you use a 20 V power supply (which is where double the input voltage stays within the part's ratings) suggests this is probably the issue.

Interestingly, the AP64501's datasheet doesn't seem to mention this potential pitfall, despite recommending low-ESR ceramic capacitors. I've seen plenty of warnings about this in datasheets for similar parts from LT and Maxim, though.

You can prevent this from happening with a properly designed input filter, or just some kind of TVS diode to absorb the overvoltage.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.
The supply line is currently about 70cm long.
But it could also be 2m long, or only 10cm long.

the input capacitor is this one: https://www.mouser.de/ProductDetail/581-1206DD106MAT2A

Can the problem you describe be solved with a better capacitor, or do I have to install a TVS or Zener diode?

Comment: @nordsektor Please add any missing information to the question itself by editing it. Then delete your comment, and flag this comment as "No longer needed".

Comment: @Hearth That's pretty much what I was thinking. I'm quite certain that's the problem. Just because the part can be used in ideal circumstances with just C1 on input doesn't mean it's even a practical configuration for many uses. Never mind the layout... if that's the "reference" layout, then I'd say they did a poor job with it.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica The reference layout in the [datasheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP64501.pdf) (page 23) seems a good deal better than what the asker's using. I'm not sure why they say they're using the reference layout.